# Unable to ping google.com

Tags: networking, ip

On a new CentOS VM, I have setup 10.x.x.x IP. I want to enable IPv4/IPv6 on this VM
But ping google.com does not work, what are the things to look for?

```
[root@vm1 ~]# ping google.com
PING google.com(ord38s31-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:81a::200e)) 56 data bytes
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4091ms
```

Virtualization Software: VMware
VM Network Adapter Type: VMXNET3

IP and route details are below

```
[root@vm1 ~]# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:b5:8a:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.85.41.126/21 brd 10.85.47.255 scope global noprefixroute ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:db8:1:0:250:56ff:feb5:8aea/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 86366sec preferred_lft 14366sec
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feb5:8aea/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens224: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:b5:cf:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 2001:db8:1:0:250:56ff:feb5:cf0c/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 86366sec preferred_lft 14366sec
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feb5:cf0c/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:7f:5f:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:7f:5f:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Route:

```
[root@vm1 ~]# ip route
default via 10.85.40.1 dev ens192 proto static metric 100
10.85.40.0/21 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 10.85.41.126 metric 100
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown


[root@vm1 ~]# ip -6 route
unreachable ::/96 dev lo metric 1024 pref medium
unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo metric 1024 pref medium
2001:db8:1::/64 dev ens192 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
2001:db8:1::/64 dev ens224 proto ra metric 101 pref medium
unreachable 2002:a00::/24 dev lo metric 1024 pref medium
unreachable 2002:7f00::/24 dev lo metric 1024 pref medium
unreachable 2002:a9fe::/32 dev lo metric 1024 pref medium
unreachable 2002:ac10::/28 dev lo metric 1024 pref medium
unreachable 2002:c0a8::/32 dev lo metric 1024 pref medium
unreachable 2002:e000::/19 dev lo metric 1024 pref medium
unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo metric 1024 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ens192 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ens224 proto kernel metric 101 pref medium
default proto ra metric 100 pref medium
    nexthop via fe80::52eb:1aff:fea7:392a dev ens192 weight 1
    nexthop via fe80::52eb:1aff:fef1:ebe2 dev ens192 weight 1
    nexthop via fe80::250:56ff:feb5:1d0e dev ens192 weight 1
default proto ra metric 101 pref medium
    nexthop via fe80::250:56ff:feb5:8aea dev ens224 weight 1
    nexthop via fe80::250:56ff:feb5:1d0e dev ens224 weight 1
    nexthop via fe80::52eb:1aff:fea7:392a dev ens224 weight 1
    nexthop via fe80::52eb:1aff:fef1:ebe2 dev ens224 weight 1
default dev lo proto ra metric 1024 pref medium
```

ping 4 works, ping 6 fails

```
[root@vm1 ~]# ping -4 google.com
PING google.com (142.250.191.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ord38s31-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.191.206): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=11.0 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.919/10.985/11.033/0.130 ms


[root@vm1 ~]# ping -6 google.com
PING google.com(ord37s36-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:814::200e)) 56 data bytes
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6181ms
```

So probably this is to do with IPv6 but I want to enable IPv4/IPv6 on this VM

Comment: Are you able to ping your router?

Comment: Do you have, and can you try ping6 for pinging IPv6 addresses?

Comment: How do I ping the router? ping/ping6 to google.com or ipv6.google.com does not work

Comment: Please provide `ip route` output. What is your router IP? Does it work (like doing NAT etc)?

Comment: Disable IP6 in the CentOS VM and try to ping again. Also, try the other suggestions from the comments. You can ping your router via its IP address or pt's hostname.

Comment: What virtualization software are you using? How is the VM connected to the network (bridge, NAT, etc)? What IP addresses does it have (`ip addr`)? What routes does it have (`ip route`)? Is the VM able to use IPv4 (`ping -4 google.com`)? Is the **host** able to use IPv6 (`ping -6 google.com` on the host)?

Comment: ...Also, what routes does it have in `ip -6 route` as well? And is that `2001:db8:1:` prefix real, or did you manually edit it in?

Comment: added output of `ip -6 route`.

Comment: Pings are pointless, we need traceroute info.

Comment: @Amol Make sure IP6 is supported/enabled by the host and by the router. If that isn't enough we may have to do further troubleshooting.